# Soap, Jquery, Ajax and an Error

Tags: 2010, error, jquery, ajax, soap

Ok, here is what I am trying to do.  I have a list on another site.  I have successfully connected to the site and pulled in the list as a dropdown using soap, ajax and jquery.  However, once I try and submit the new item, it gives me an error.  Here is the code I am using,

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var soapEnv =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
            <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>b9ac31cc-ea35-4df1-af50-4e3fa9e86b1c</listName> \
                <viewName>7E918A0F-631B-4B3B-81FD-B27C98586DC4</viewName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                            <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                        </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "/sites/wellness/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"'
    });

    $('#addThis').bind('click',function(){
        var choice = $('#chooseOrg').val();
        alert(choice);
        $('#ctl00_m_g_03d6c665_34ef_42f1_9e55_ae2a2560edc7_ff4_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val(choice)
    });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
        //$('#chooseOrg').
        $('#ctl00_m_g_83e35e85_85ae_4056_9d87_b56fe029295b_ff41_ctl00_DropDownChoice').
        append($("<option></option>").
        attr("value",$(this).attr("ows_Title")).
        text($(this).attr("ows_Title")));
    });
};
</script>
```

Here is the Error Screen.
[image: Image of error]

If I remove the soap/ajax/and jquery it adds a new item like it is supposed to, Any Ideas??

Comment: Can you find the Correlation ID in the logs and post the relevant error messages?

Comment: I don't have access to the error logs, I have sent the request to another member on my team to see if they can find them for me.  Any ideas without??

Comment: Well that's the error that displays for almost every error in SharePoint. Have you tried tracing it with FireBug or IE F12 Developer Tools to see what the service response is?

Comment: I mean, you are using a relative url. Are you sure the endpoint is available from the location you're running it?

Comment: Yes, it is available, If I take out the dynamic dropdown options, sharepoint saves just like it is supposed to

Comment: Sorry, I don't know without more information, I've just been staring at this for the last 10 minutes...

Comment: I don't get your last sentence. If you remove the code then everything works like magic???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the options you are adding to the select don't have the same ids as the values in the source list. You're using the Title for both the option text and the value. Assuming that the DropDownChoice is a Lookup column, you need to use the right id for each option to match what would be saved if you weren't running your script.

Comment: ok, do you know of a way to add them to the list column?  I am not sure how to do that. The list column is a "Choice" dropdown.

Comment: You can't add arbitrary values to the Choice column dropdown; the only values which are allowable are those which you've got in the list settings.

Comment: ok, thanks for you assistance on this.  What I ended up doing was pulling in the values into the dropdown and then having the user add that to a textbox.  It works good, a bit klunky but it works.

Comment: You could add those disallowed values to the text box yourself in your script, since you'll know which ones you've added.